# Do capital letters in variables make a difference in Serialization?

Tags: java, android, list, api, serialization

I've discovered (the hard way) that variables with all capital letters in my Android Java code, are not being serialized to bytes and sent via Rest Api to my Java backend server.

When both client and server use `**ABC**` as the variable name, the server receives a null value for this variable.

When both client and server use `**abc**` as the variable in lower case, then it serializes correctly, and the server receives the correct response.

Why is this the case, because if I was using Final values, then they would have been in capitals anyway?

The variable was this:

```
List<Object> OBJ;
```

Does it matter if the variable was a List?

Comment: Are you able to provide what libraries you are using to serialize and send the data to your backend?

Comment: I am using java.io to convert to a byte array, then Retrofit to send the API JSON from Android, then Spring boot server side. Everything is very generic.

Comment: Writing variables in `ALL_CAPS_LIKE_THIS` is for __constants__. `final` does not mean _constant_. `ALL_CAPS` is appropriate if [A] it is final, _and_ [B] it is `static`, _and_ [C] it is _not_ a reference to a mutable thing. e.g. `static final List<String> ITEMS = new ArrayList<String>();` is still not correct - an arraylist is not immutable. `static final List<String> ITEMS = List.of("A", "B")` would be appropriate - `List.of` returns immutable lists. You need all 3.

Comment: Check the 'wire' - but here's my guess: Given that the naming is all-caps, retrofit thinks its a constant and therefore doesn't send it. What possible point is there in sending constant info? (See my previous comment that explains what a constant is. It's not just something marked `final` - it's something whose value is known at compile time, essentially), and therefore it doesn't send it at all.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Could be the case. It is an interesting guess. But I would have thought a constant can be sent in an API call by Retrofit as I can imagine a few use case scenarios for this, particularly as some objects may need constant values. I will test it.

Comment: Use Retrofit with a GSON serialization adapter and then make your object a GSON object. It's pretty much a standard in the industry for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) for serialisation and provide the name of variable that is expected by the api in the @SerializedName("api_name") and keep the actual name of variable any way you want.